# How can I create a random dummy variable of 2000 observations in R and Stata?

Tags: r, stata

I want to create a random dummy (1 and 0) variable in R or Stata, but how can I make that, for example, 70% of observations be 1 and the rest 0. Thanks

Comment: @IanCampbell, please post your comment as an answer ... (may be worth noting that it only gives *approximately* 70% ones, i.e. up to binomial error ...)

Comment: Thanks so much! Just in case, do you know how to replicate that in stata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `sample` from base R:

```
sample(c(1,0), size = 2000, prob = c(0.7,0.3), replace = TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
#[58] 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

As @Ben Bolker points out in the comments, it would be unusual for exactly 1400 to be `1`.

This approach will result in exactly 1400 `1`s:

```
sample(rep(c(1,0),c(1400,600)), 2000)
```

Comment: I suggest you use `rbinom` instead of sample when sampling from the binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted *exactly* 70% of 1s (or any other percentage), but a *random ordering* of the elements, you can use this function.

```
random_binary <- function(n, p){
  # p is the proportion of 1s
  x <- c(rep(1, times=n * p), rep(0, times=n * (1 - p)))
  x[sample(length(x))] # or sample(x)
}

random_binary(10, 0.7)
#[1] 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

The `times` argument of `rep` can be non-integer, as mentioned in the documentation.

```
? rep
```

`times`

> A double vector is accepted, other inputs being coerced to an integer
>   or double vector.

But note that you may not get exactly the percentage desired (but as close as possible).

An alternative is to use `rbinom`, since we're effectively sampling from the binomial distribution.

```
rbinom(10, size=1, p=0.7)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
```

This is similar to `sample` with the `prob` argument and, as shown above, does not guarantee to return exactly 70% of 1s.

Answer (score 1):

In Stata for exactly 70% 1s and 30% 0s

```
set obs 2000
set seed 1606
gen wanted = cond(_n <= 70, 1, 0) 
gen random = runiform()
sort random
```

For approximately 70% 1s and 30% 0s

```
gen better = runiform() < 0.7
```